# How to Clone a TFS Repository with a Hyphen in the name Using git-tf

Tags: git, git-tf

Please help!  I've been banging my head against the wall all week on this one!  When I attempt to clone an repository with a long dash in its name, I get a repository not found error.  I have tried all sorts of ways to escape it with not luck.

Here is my code:

```
git tf clone -b --branches "<servername>" "$/Tech Consulting – Conversions/Infinity Conversion Tools/Conversion Engine"
```

Comment: What platform is this?

Comment: Are you specifying your collection URI correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Seven years after this question was asked, I had the same problem. I am on Windows 10 using git bash. I used the Windows emoji keyboard (accessed by Windows key plus period) to enter a medium length dash on the command line, and this allowed me to match the name of the TFS branch I was trying to clone.